# How to automatize this process?

Tags: facebook, automation, imacros, browser-automation

I need a automatization script for a facebook. 
Im thinking how i can do this and in which program.. I was thinking about imacros but i don't think that imacros can open new tabs etc. 
I don't have any experience with programming so i need a easy program to do this.

Script have to look like this :

1) open incognito tab, log on facebook with login/pass from .txt (if account doesnt work, try another login/pass)

2) go to site X, accept all permisions

3) go to facebook again and open browser console and type code from .txt (always the same code)

4) code will open another site, where script need to copy the site adress to a .txt file

5) close incognito tab

6) repeat till accounts from .txt will end or i will stop the process.

Comment: what is your budget?

Comment: i am pretty sure those things are not allowed. for testing, use test users with the api.

Comment: That does not sound as if it would have any remotely legal application ...

Answer (score 0):

@gitara

You can try in different ways for this. I can suggest you one simple solution i.e. explore

> Selenium WebDriverWith Java (any language of your interest).

Selenium would be simplest and opensource solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIPath framework, This is used to automate process in Web application.
https://www.uipath.com/